# Angular 5: unable to show the value in html view from function

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to show the value generated by the function. In the html file, I wrote the following:

```
<input type="text" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)" class="form-control validate" #card="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="cardNumber" maxlength="16" name="cardNumber" placeholder="cardNumber" required /> 

<p>Type= {{payCardType}}</p>
```

In the component.ts file, I wrote the below function:

```
onSearchChange(searchValue : string ) {  
        //console.log("val="+searchValue);
        let regexMap = [
          {regEx: /^4[0-9]{5}/ig,cardType: "VISA"},
          {regEx: /^5[1-5][0-9]{4}/ig,cardType: "MASTERCARD"},
          {regEx: /^3[47][0-9]{3}/ig,cardType: "AMEX"},
          {regEx: /^(5[06-8]\d{4}|6\d{5})/ig,cardType: "MAESTRO"}
        ];

        for (let j = 0; j < regexMap.length; j++) {
          if (searchValue.match(regexMap[j].regEx)) {
            let payCardType = regexMap[j].cardType;
            console.log(payCardType);
            return payCardType;
            break;
          }
        }
    }
```

I can see the value generated in the console however, I can't see the value in the HTML file.

Comment: As a side note : `(input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)" #card="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="cardNumber"` are all redundant. Consider reducing it to `(input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the found value to the component member using `this.payCardType`:

```
this.payCardType = '';

for (let j = 0; j < regexMap.length; j++) {
  if (searchValue.match(regexMap[j].regEx)) {
    this.payCardType = regexMap[j].cardType;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'ngModelChange' instead of 'input'.

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)" class="form-control validate" #card="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="cardNumber" maxlength="16" name="cardNumber" placeholder="cardNumber" required /> 

<p>Type= {{payCardType}}</p>

In component:

payCardType;
onSearchChange(searchValue : string ) {  
        //console.log("val="+searchValue);
        let regexMap = [
          {regEx: /^4[0-9]{5}/ig,cardType: "VISA"},
          {regEx: /^5[1-5][0-9]{4}/ig,cardType: "MASTERCARD"},
          {regEx: /^3[47][0-9]{3}/ig,cardType: "AMEX"},
          {regEx: /^(5[06-8]\d{4}|6\d{5})/ig,cardType: "MAESTRO"}
        ];

        for (let j = 0; j < regexMap.length; j++) {
          if (searchValue.match(regexMap[j].regEx)) {
            let payCardType = regexMap[j].cardType;
            console.log(payCardType);
            this.payCardType =  payCardType;
            break;
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update statement:

```
payCardType: any;

this.payCardType = regexMap[j].cardType;
```